# Can I move index.js in create-react-app to an nested folder?

Tags: reactjs

I know that based on [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure) folder structure, the `index.js` file should be directly inside `src` folder.

However, based on a requirement, I need to move it to `src/Base` directory.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

You have to eject webpack and change the entry to 'src/base/index'.

example with eject webpack:

- npm run eject
- In config/paths.js change appIndexJs from resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index') to resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/base/index').
- In package.json change scripts:

  "start": "node scripts/start.js",
  "build": "node scripts/build.js",
  "test": "node scripts/test.js"

Example without eject webpack:

- Use Craco config override entry webpack.

Comment: This is why I never use create-react-app in any of real projects.

Comment: what do you use then